# Need clear steps on how to convert a Windows 2000 Server to a XenServer VM

Tags: windows, virtualization, xenserver, virtual-machines, physical-to-virtual

The source system is not local. The target host running XenServer is not local.

The source system is running Windows 2000 Server SP4 and has 1 disk split into 6 partitions, all NTFS:

C: 6 GB (boot)
D: 15 GB
E: 6 GB
F: 6 GB
G: 5 GB
H: 26 GB

Most of the partitions are mostly mostly full (> 60%).

What is the most straightforward way to do a P2V migration of the server?  I can do minor database & data syncs after the P2V is successful & running as a VM within XenServer, it's just getting to that point which is not clear.

The option of installing a Windows 2000 Server from scratch is not available, I need to convert the existing physical server as-is into a VM to be hosted within a XenServer environment.

I've looked at XenConvert but it maxes out on converting only 4 partitions in one shot, and I'm not certain how to account for the 2 extra partitions.  I'm not familiar with XenServer but it's my only option right now to go P2V.

Comment: Don't. Microsoft is ceasing support for Windows 2000 in a few months.

Comment: I'm asking for help with a procedure, the fact Microsoft is ceasing support for Windows 2K is irrelevant to my question. I only need to do this once for one server. It's also safer for me to test an upgrade to 2003 in a virtual environment before decommissioning the physical server.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could just convert/move the first 4 partitions (or even just the main partition) and after firing up your VM, you could add the rest via virtual disks.

Comment: OK, I was hoping to maintain the VM as a single Xen VM file to make it easier to figure out the backup/restore options. I shifted some stuff around and can do the P2V with just 4 of the partitions and not need the others, I'll just end up with drive letter gaps (C:, D:, F:, H:).